# seccion de comentarios ¿como hacer para que un usuario no borre o edite el comentario que hizo otra persona?

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

hola tengo una duda que espero me puedan resolver, les explico estoy creando una seccion de comentarios para mi pagina web y les puse la opcion de que se pudiera eliminar o editar el comentario, el caso es que si yo por ejemplo pongo un comentario otra persona tambien lo puede editar o eliminar y eso pues no debe ser asi, entonces como podria evitar eso, como puedo hacer para que solo la persona que escribio el comentario lo pueda editar o eliminar?

**Codigo de la parte de editar y eliminar**

```
<div>

    <?php
    $cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "comentarios_db");
    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, comentario FROM t_comentarios order by id desc";
    $rta = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
    while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($rta)) {
    ?>
        <div class="caja_comentarios">
            <p><b><?php echo $mostrar['nombre'] ?></b></p>
            <hr>
            <p><?php echo $mostrar['comentario'] ?></p>

            <p>
                <b>
                    <a href="editar.php?
                    id= <?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?> &
                    nombre= <?php echo $mostrar['nombre'] ?> &
                    comentario= <?php echo $mostrar['comentario'] ?>
                    ">Editar</a>
                    <a href="sp_eliminar.php? id= <?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?>">Eliminar</a>
                </b>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>


</div>
```

**codigo editar.php**

```
    <body>
    <?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $comentario = $_GET['comentario'];
    ?>

    <div class="edit-comentario">
        <form action="sp_editar.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id" style="visibility:hidden;" value="<?= $id ?>">
            <div class="edit">
                <p>NOMBRE:</p>
                <p><input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?= $nombre ?>" class="nom-edit"></p>
                <p>COMENTARIO</td>
                <p><input type="text" name="comentario" value="<?= $comentario ?>" class="com-edit"></p>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" class="btn-actualizar">
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="inicio.php"> <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i><b>Regresar</b></a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**codigo sp_eliminar.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "comentarios_db");
$sql = "DELETE FROM t_comentarios where id like $id";
$rta = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);

if (!$rta) {
    echo "NO SE ELIMINO!";
}else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

**codigo sp_editar.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

$cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "comentarios_db");
$sql = "UPDATE t_comentarios SET nombre = '$nombre', comentario ='$comentario' where id like $id";
$rta = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);

if (!$rta) {
    echo "NO SE ACTUALIZO!";
}else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: No tengo idea de cómo hacerlo pero supongo que, lógicamente, deberías agregar una consulta de tipo `IF` por ejemplo: si el comentario tiene un id asociado a un usuario, entonces preguntas si ese usuario hizo el comentario. Si lo hizo, puede editar/eliminar

Comment: Podrías identificar a la persona de alguna manera. O mejor aún, para qué reinventar la rueda si puedes usar un sistema de comentarios ya hecho. Por ejemplo https://commento.io/ o https://fastcomments.com/

Comment: Se puede hacer de muchas formas. Pero si no vemos el codigo no podemos adivinar donde será mejor implementar esto en tu proyecto.

Comment: La tabla de comentarios debe tener mínimo estos campos: `id`, `post_id` (fk -> tabla_post), `user_id` (fk -> tabla_usuarios), `comment`, `created_at`, `updated_at`. Con esa estructura, en PHP tienes que trabajar con [sesiones](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+sesiones), y si el usuario `$_SESSION['user_id'] == $comment['user_id']` lo dejas editar. Puedes agregar otra condición, si el usuario es admin `or $_SESSION['privilege'] == 'admin'`, entonces lo dejas editar ese comentario, y cualquier otro.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en SO prefiramos dudas sobre código, por ser mucho más concreto. Lo que planteas tampoco debería generar mucho debate. A riesgo de que la pregunta termine cerrada, te respondo:

> Guarda el `id` del autor en cada comentario y, al editar, te aseguras
> de que el editor sea el mismo que el autor. Para poder saber el `id` del
> autor y del editor, únicamente tienes que pedirles que se validen con
> un sistema de login, bien al entrar al sistema, o al publicar o
> editar, eso ya depende de la interfaz de usuario y usabilidad que
> diseñes. El `id_autor` lo tendrán en la base de datos y el `id_editor` en la variable `$_SESSION['id_editor']` que generarás tras la autentificación o login.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y, si acompañas a tu pregunta de un código mínimo que lo ilustre, mejor.

En respuesta al código que aportas, te propongo estas modificaciones al fichero `inicio.php`:

```
<?php
$cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "comentarios_db");

// gestión de la sesión del editor
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
    unset($_SESSION);
if(isset($_POST['editor'])){
    $editores=$cnx->query("
        SELECT * FROM t_autores;
    ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($editores as $e)
        if($_POST['editor']==$e['autor'] 
            and hash('SHA256',$_POST['contrasena'])==$e['contrasena'])
                $_SESSION['id_editor']=$e['id_autor'];
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_editor'])){
    echo '<form method="post" action="inicio.php">
        <input type="text" name="editor" placeholder="editor"/>
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="contraseña"/>
        <button>Identificarse</button>
    </form>';
}
else echo '<div><a href="?logout=1">Cerrar sesión</a></div>';

// lista de comentarios
echo '<div>';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_comentarios order by id desc";
$rta = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($rta)) {
    echo '
        <div class="caja_comentarios">
            <p><b>'.$mostrar['nombre'].'</b></p>
            <hr>
            <p>'.$mostrar['comentario'].'</p>
            <p>';
    if(isset($_SESSION['id_editor'])
        and $_SESSION['id_editor']==$mostrar['id_editor'])
            echo '
                <b>
                    <a href="editar.php?id='.$mostrar['id']
                        .'&nombre='.$mostrar['nombre']
                        .'&comentario='.$mostrar['comentario'].'">Editar</a>
                    <a href="sp_eliminar.php?id='.$mostrar['id'].'">Eliminar</a>
                </b>
            ';
    echo '
            </p>
        </div>
    ';
}
echo '<div>';
```

Así como a la base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE t_autores(
  id_autor int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  autor varchar(15),
  contrasena char(64)  
  );

ALTER TABLE t_comentarios
  ADD id_editor int,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_editor) REFERENCES t_autores(id_autor);

UPDATE t_comentarios
  set id_editor=1;
```

Para popular la base de datos de autores con una codificación de la contraseña compatible con la del código PHP, deberías insertar los editores así:

```
INSERT INTO t_autores (autor, contrasena) VALUES
  ('Marilu',SHA2('1234',256)),
  ('David',SHA2('1234',256));
```

Aporto el dataset original, por si alguien quiere probar el código:

```
CREATE DATABASE comentarios_db;
USE comentarios_db;

CREATE TABLE t_comentarios(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  comentario text
  );
INSERT INTO t_comentarios (nombre, comentario) VALUES
  ('nombre1','comentario1');
```

Si quieres más seguridad, también puedes comprobar el editor antes de realizar el `UPDATE`.

Comment: ya puse el codigo en la parte de editar y eliminar

Comment: @MariluAlfaro He ampliado tu código con un formulario de login para que puedas autentificar a los editores y únicamente éstos puedan modificar los comentarios